# Move bootstrap column up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to push the column up, I'm not sure how to do it. This is my code

```
 <!-- Main content -->
            <section class="content">


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="sm-st clearfix">
                        <span class="sm-st-icon st-red"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                        <div class="sm-st-info">
                            <span><?php echo $slots;?></span>
                            Slots Booked  this week
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="sm-st clearfix">
                        <span class="sm-st-icon st-violet"><i class="fa fa-headphones"></i></span>
                        <div class="sm-st-info">
                            <span><?php echo $listeners;?></span>
                            Listeners tuned in now
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="sm-st clearfix">
                        <span class="sm-st-icon st-blue"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
                        <div class="sm-st-info">
                            <span>21</span>
                            Requests sent in
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="sm-st clearfix">
                        <span class="sm-st-icon st-green"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>
                        <div class="sm-st-info">
                            <span>18</span>
                            Staff
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <section class="panel">
                        <header class="panel-heading">

                        </header>
                        <div class="panel-body">

                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <section class="panel">
                        <header class="panel-heading">
                            Last 15 played song.
                        </header>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Artist</th>
                                    <th>Track</th>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                                echo $tracks;
                                ?>

                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <!--earning graph start-->
                    <section class="panel">
                        <header class="panel-heading">
                            6 hour Listener Graph
                        </header>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <canvas id="linechart" width="500" height="330" style="width:100%;"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                 </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <!--chat start-->
                    <section class="panel">
                        <header class="panel-heading">
                            Whats been Happen-taning!
                        </header>
                        <div class="panel-body" id="noti-box">
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>


            </section><!-- /.content -->
```

I want to push the (Listener Graph) panel under the rules column. Im not sure how to do this, if it isnt clear here is a picture of what im trying to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G56kn.png

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i was being stupid.

Just put them in the same column instead of have multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

You put **class="row"** over your panel. Remove the **class="row"**. Row means one line in a horizontal way. So it takes "**Last 15 played songs**" and "By looking slots..... (panel)" as a row.